# Problems with calculating Strontium-90 leakage due to Fukushima accident

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation, radioactivity

Not long ago there was a spill of radioactive water at the Fukushima plants. Here are the data:

$230 \times 10^6 \,\,\mathrm{Bq}$ of beta radiation are found in a liter of water.

$t_{1/2} = 28.79 \,\,\mathrm{years}$

100 tons of water were spilled.

Doing the calculations according to the formula:

$A_{bq}=\frac{m}{m_a}N_A\frac{\ln{2}}{t_{1/2}}$

I'm concluding that only 4.5 grams were spilled. This is the first time I do this sort of calculation. This number seems ridiculously small! Does 4.5 grams really present a threat? Am I doing something wrong?

In case of interest, source: http://www.nytimes.com/2014/02/21/world/asia/worst-spill-in-6-months-at-fukushima.html?module=Search&mabReward=relbias%3Ar%2C%7B%222%22%3A%22RI%3A17%22%7D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, Strontium accumulates in the bones replacing Calcium, so you can't easily get rid of it. Second, the most radioactive natural food we eat is the banana, at about 130 becquerels per Kg. So that 1L of "hot" water really is quite nasty if you drink it and a significant portion of the Sr90 ends up in your bones.

Comment: Do you mean to say that its a normal thing to say something is "very dangerous" even if there is so little quantity involved?

Comment: One microgram of Polonium is a lethal dose. I doubt whether you could even see it.